# Powershell Scripting

Tags: powershell

Can you help me on my script to do a website automated checking that will display CNAME, A and AAAA records, Redirection domain? Also need to put a blank row for every 3 websites.

I tried this sample script, but it does not display all CNAME's

```
$NameList = @("w88live.com", "www.w88live.com", "m.w88live.com", "w88io.com", "www.w88io.com", "m.w88io.com")
$FinalResult = @()

foreach ($Name in ($NameList)) {
    $tempObj = "" | Select-Object Name, PrimaryServer, IPAddress, Redirection 

    try {
        $dnsRecord = Resolve-DnsName  $Name -ErrorAction Stop -Type CNAME
        $dnsRecord1 = Resolve-DnsName $Name -ErrorAction Stop -Type A_AAAA
        $dnsRecord2 = invoke-webrequest -uri $Name -DisableKeepAlive -MaximumRedirection 0 -TimeoutSec 5 -ErrorAction Ignore -Method Head 
        $dnsRecord3 = Resolve-DnsName $Name -ErrorAction Stop -Type NS
        #$dnsRecord2 = invoke-webrequest -UseBasicParsing $Name -DisableKeepAlive -MaximumRedirection 0 -TimeoutSec 10 -ErrorAction Stop
        $tempObj.Redirection = ($dnsRecord2.Headers.Location -join "")
        $tempObj.Name = $Name 
        $tempObj.PrimaryServer = ($dnsRecord.PrimaryServer -join " / ")
        $tempObj.IPAddress = ($dnsRecord1.IPAddress -join ' / ')
    }
    catch { 
        $tempObj.Redirection = ($dnsRecord2.Headers.Location -join "")
        $tempObj.Name = $Name 
        $tempObj.PrimaryServer = ($dnsRecord.PrimaryServer -join " / ")
        $tempObj.IPAddress = ($dnsRecord1.IPAddress -join ' / ') 

    }   
 
    $FinalResult += $tempObj
}

return $FinalResult
```

I'm new to this powershell that's why I badly need assistance. Hope someone with good heart can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: What script??? Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry forgot to put the script im using.

Comment: Use a For loop instead of ForEach to count every third Name : for($i = 0; $i -lt $NameList.Count; $i++){ if(($i % 3) -eq 0) {Write-Host "`n"}; $Name = $NameList[$i]; Write-Host $Name}

Comment: may i see the sample command please? Im new on powershell. didnt get what you mean

Comment: I tried to put it @jdweng but it doesnt have output on csv file. Can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start

```
$NameList = @("w88live.com", "www.w88live.com", "m.w88live.com", "w88io.com", "www.w88io.com", "m.w88io.com")
$FinalResult = @()

for($i = 0; $i -lt $NameList.Count; $i++) {
    if(($i % 3) -eq 2) 
    {
       $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
       $FinalResult += $newRow
    };
    $Name = $NameList[$i];
    $tempObj = "" | Select-Object Name, PrimaryServer, IPAddress, Redirection 

    try {
        $dnsRecord = Resolve-DnsName  $Name -ErrorAction Stop -Type CNAME
        $dnsRecord1 = Resolve-DnsName $Name -ErrorAction Stop -Type A_AAAA
        $dnsRecord2 = invoke-webrequest -uri $Name -DisableKeepAlive -MaximumRedirection 0 -TimeoutSec 5 -ErrorAction Ignore -Method Head 
        $dnsRecord3 = Resolve-DnsName $Name -ErrorAction Stop -Type NS
        #$dnsRecord2 = invoke-webrequest -UseBasicParsing $Name -DisableKeepAlive -MaximumRedirection 0 -TimeoutSec 10 -ErrorAction Stop
        $tempObj.Redirection = ($dnsRecord2.Headers.Location -join "")
        $tempObj.Name = $Name 
        $tempObj.PrimaryServer = ($dnsRecord.PrimaryServer -join " / ")
        $tempObj.IPAddress = ($dnsRecord1.IPAddress -join ' / ')
    }
    catch { 
        $tempObj.Redirection = ($dnsRecord2.Headers.Location -join "")
        $tempObj.Name = $Name 
        $tempObj.PrimaryServer = ($dnsRecord.PrimaryServer -join " / ")
        $tempObj.IPAddress = ($dnsRecord1.IPAddress -join ' / ') 

    }   
 
    $FinalResult += $tempObj
}

return $FinalResult
```

Comment: Hi @jdweng, it works but i just noticed the row for name, primary server IP address and redirection is included for every 3 counts.

Comment: How to separate the row for Name, primaryserver, IP address and redirection for every 3 counts? Just wanted to start the count for every 3 of our company websites.

Comment: But the value is null.

Comment: what you mean bro?

Comment: is it not possible? to separate row for Name, primaryserver, IP address and redirection. and the start for counting  is from w88live.com

Comment: The results is a table.  You can't have a table with some rows containing values in columns and other do not have  values.